# How to keep checkboxes checked in PHP email form

Tags: php, forms

I have a long web form that emails to an address once it is submitted. If there are errors with the form it alerts the user but leaves the values already entered on the form. The only thing I can't get to work is the checkboxes. The info from them are emailed no problem, but if there are errors then the checkboxes come back blank, even if they were filled out. How can I get them to stay checked? Any help would be great!

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Bad breath" name="element_1[]" id="element_1_10" <?php if ($cf['posted_form_data']['problems'] == 'Bad breath') echo 'checked'; ?> class="checkbox"> Bad breath
```

PHP form

```
if(isset($_POST['element_1']) && is_array($_POST['element_1']))
        {
         $problems=implode(" | ",$_POST['element_1']);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add to the checkbox input 'checked="checked"'

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" <?php if($err && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. There are a few of them in an array, if that makes a difference.